# Tell compiler that implicit conversion exists for generic type

Tags: c#, generics, compiler-errors

Consider the following code;

```cs
class SomeType1
{
}

class SomeType2
{
}

class CombinedType
{
    public static implicit operator CombinedType(SomeType1 source)
    {
        return new CombinedType
        {
            ...
        };
    }

    public static implicit operator CombinedType(SomeType2 source)
    {
        return new CombinedType
        {
            ...
        };
    }
}

void SomeMethod()
{
    var listOfType1 = new List<SomeType1>();
    DoSomethingWith(listOfType1);

    var listOfType2 = new List<SomeType2>();
    DoSomethingWith(listOfType2);
}

void DoSomethingWith<T>(IEnumerable<T> stuff)
{
    IEnumerable<CombinedType> converted = stuff.Select(i => (CombinedType) i);
    ...
}
```

This fails with

> Error CS0030  Cannot convert type 'T' to 'CombinedType'

However, I know that an implicit conversion exists between `T` and `CombinedType` when `T` is either `SomeType1` or `SomeType2`. How can I tell the compiler that this should be possible? I cannot add `where T : CombinedType` on the generic method because that is not true.

Comment: How do you call `DoSomethingWith`? Do you know when you call it whether you've got an `IEnumerable<SomeType1>` or an `IEnumerable<SomeType2>`?

Answer (score 3):

Implicit conversions are just method calls which are inserted by the compiler at compile time.

For example:

```
CombinedType c = new SomeType1();
```

gets turned into:

```
CombinedType c = CombinedType.op_Implicit(new SomeType1());
```

The JIT doesn't have the knowledge to insert these method calls. Yet, generics are expanded at JIT-time, which is when you want this to happen.

Don't forget that your code also allows someone to pass in a `T` which isn't convertible to a `CombinedType`.

---

You've got a few options, however.

One is:

```
void DoSomethingWith<T>(IEnumerable<T> stuff)
{
    IEnumerable<CombinedType> converted = stuff.Select(i => i switch
    {
        SomeType1 s1 => (CombinedType)s1,
        SomeType2 s2 => (CombinedType)s2,
        _ => throw ...
    });
}
```

Another is something like:

```
public interface IConvertibleToCombinedType
{
    CombinedType ConvertToCombinedType();
}

public class SomeType1 : IConvertibleToCombinedType
{
    // ... or get rid of the implicit conversion, and put the logic here
    public CombinedType ConvertToCombinedType() => this;
}

public class SomeType2 : IConvertibleToCombinedType
{
   ...
}

void DoSomethingWith<T>(IEnumerable<T> stuff) where T : IConvertibleToCombinedType
{
    IEnumerable<CombinedType> converted = stuff.Select(i => ConvertToCombinedType());
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think option 1 is the one that will help me. I mentioned on the other answer I do not have access to the source of `SomeType1` so cannot add additional interfaces.

Comment: @Steztric That's the sort of information that it would be very helpful to include in your question.

Comment: The `switch` approach can also be put in `CombinedType`. Namely if you in the `CombinedType` class put this method: `public static CombinedType Create<T>(T t)
    {
      switch (t)
      {
        case SomeType1 st1: return st1;
        case SomeType2 st2: return st2;
        default: throw new ArgumentException();
      }
    }` (or similar with C# 8 syntax). Then you can write your select as: `IEnumerable<CombinedType> converted = stuff.Select(CombinedType.Create)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a shared dummy interface like `interface ICombinedType {}`, make all 3 classes implement it, and then add `where T : ICombinedType` to the generic method.

Comment: Would be a nice idea, but I don't actually have access to the source of `SomeType1`, it comes from a library.